# Concrete5 5.7: How to use the dialog popup on package dashboard single pages

Tags: concrete5, concrete5-5.7

I have a **package** with a dashboard single page. On this single page I need a dynamically created **dialog** popup, and so
I also need to use the router, views (`package/mypackage/views`) and controllers.

The questions now are the following:

- What looks the directory structure like?
- Where and how do I use `Router::register('what_path_?', 'Namespace\?\Class::method')` to create the route to the view/controller?
- How do I call upon the route inside the single page view (`Url::to(?)`) and in combination with the dialog JS?

*Please add comments if some questions are still open!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To create modal dialogs** on dashboard single pages in packages, the following steps are necessary (assuming the package already exists):

- Creating the following supplementary files / folders (for sake of readability):

  ```
  /my_package/controllers/dialog/my_dialog.php
  /my_package/views/dialogs/my_dialog.php
  ```
- The 'my_dialog' controller should look like this:

  ```
  namespace Concrete\Package\MyPackage\Controller\Dialog;

  use Concrete\Core\Controller\Controller;

  class MyDialog extends Controller
  {
      protected $viewPath = 'dialogs/my_dialog';

      public function view()
      {
          /** your code */
      }
  }
  ```
- The 'my_dialog' view is a standard Concrete5 view.
- Add (if not exists) the following method inside the *package controller*:

  ```
  public function on_start()
  {
      Route::register('/my_package/my_dialog',
      '\Concrete\Package\MyPackage\Controller\Dialog\MyDialog::view');
  }
  ```
- Now in the *single page view*:

  ```
  <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-button="my-dialog">My dialog</a>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      $('a[data-button=add-event]').on('click', function() {
          $.fn.dialog.open({
              href: '<?= URL::to('/my_package/my_dialog'); ?>',
              title: 'My dialog',
              width: '280',
              height: '220',
              modal: true
          });
          return false;
      });
  </script>
  ```

**To note:**

The route can be named however one wants it (ex.: `/superuser/needs/new/pants`).

The call on the dialog JS might be better handled, please comment on it.

Answer (score 2):

In concrete5, you can use `$.fn.dialog.open`, for example:

```javascript
$.fn.dialog.open({
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    element: $('<div>This is an example!</div>')
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my question was not elaborated enough though. Your solution is for inline code and works well, my needs are slightly different though and therefor I have modified my question.

Comment: @Marc-AndréAppel You changed your question to a fundamentally different question and then answered it yourself. That's not how stackoverflow is meant to work, you should've opened a new question.

Comment: I'm sorry for that misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

To add another "inline-code" possibilty:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="my_dialog" style="display: none">
    <div>
          This is an example!
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#my_dialog').dialog({
    title: 'My Title',
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    modal: true,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Yes',
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-confirm"
            },
            click: function () {
                // Confirmed code
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'No',
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-cancel"
            },
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    ]
});
```